# Running MariaDB 10.3 for a Magento 1.8 install

Tags: magento-1.8, database

we have had a legacy magento site, and was wandering if anyone had tested mariaDB with magento 1.8 or 1.9 for compatiblity and whether upgrading our mariaDB install would cause any issues with magento 1. I am aware that mariaDB is not support, but it would be good to find out if someone has tested this in the past

Answer (score 0):

We just upgraded our client's websites from mysql to MariaDB 10.3. Took a few hours to optimize, but now the server is running much cooler.  About 60% less load running Magento 1.9.2.4 using PHP7.2.22 & MariaDB 10.3.  Was the best thing we did this year! I would recommend using a totally separate server to run your test.  Do not use the same server you re running on unless you can handle multiple DB solutions at a time.  Mysql + MariaDB 10.3.